# Image on category page without product information

Tags: category

At the moment magento is using the images i uploaded and includes the other information (description, price, 'as low as' price and 'add to cart' option). Instead of this, I want to create an image for each product, as I have for the first product below, but have my own text information included in the image. Therefor I only want an image displayed, no other information. I still need it to link through to that product.

How could I achieve this? Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the theme supports it, you can set the *Used in Product Listing* attribute to *No*, in the admin, Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes, select an attribute. Looking at the screenshot, you probably need to do this for *name* and *price* attributes only. Reindex and cache clear are necessary after this.

If the theme doesn't support it, then you have to change/overwrite the template that renders that section, most commonly *catalog/product/list.phtml*.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

Create an attribute named `my_image` and make sure you set it as `Media Image` and apply this attribute to all of your `Attribute Sets`.

Now, go to your desired product's image section and upload the image and set this image to newly created attribute (my_image) and also exclude it if you don't want to show in more image section.

**Note: if you simply want to upload image as main image or small image or thumb image then don't need to do above**

And then go to your `template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and change `<img` section as follow:

```
<?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'my_image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(950, null).'"/>';?>
```

If you have decided to upload the image as `small image` then change as this:

```
<?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(950, null).'"/>';?>
```

If you have decided to upload the image as `thumb image` then change as this:

```
<?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(950, null).'"/>';?>
```

If you have decided to upload the image as `main image` then change as this:

```
<?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(950, null).'"/>';?>
```

**And delete all other not needed information.**